# Odd, funky festivals in the Northeast of the US?

Tags: usa, events, festivals

My best friend is getting married and I am planning a bachelor party. This friend is an odd guy in the very best way. He laughs uncontrollably at the mere sight of a manatee and he is prone to go hiking in the nude. Previously, he visited the World Beard and Mustache Championship in Carson City, Nevada, and had the time of his life. I am looking for a similar event on the East Coast - something offbeat, a gathering of characters, something... weird.

Any festivals or other events during the warm-weather months in the Northeast, within a reasonable drive from New York City?

Comment: There are 14 states on the east coast, including many large, diverse cities.  This makes the question rather broad, and at risk of getting close votes. Any chance of being more specific - a particular state, perhaps?

Comment: @MarkMayo - Made it more specific. Lemme know if still not specific enough.

Comment: Presumably you also have a timeframe in mind?

Comment: If this guy is ever in the UK, send him my way and we'll grab a pint. He sounds awesome.

Comment: @SamtheBrand - please indicate a time-period as well for this party - otherwise people are going to be posting events from any time of the year - it'd be too broad...

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this will help but I am sure that some of these strange -> weird -> bizarre sports have presence and competitions in the NorthEast US.  I haven't gone through all of them but you are welcome to search. :)

[Complete List of Unusual Sports](http://www.topendsports.com/sport/unusual/list.htm)

Present locally:

- [Bike Polo](http://nycbikepolo.com/)
- [Chess Boxing](http://www.facebook.com/pages/NYC-ChessBoxing/141286855908260)

P.S.  Some of these sports are painful just to read about.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know when you will be doing this, but try the East Coast Kinetic Sculpture race - http://www.kineticbaltimore.com/

From the website:

> Kinetic Sculptures are amphibious, human powered works of art custom
>   built for the race. Each May, the American Visionary Art Museum (AVAM)
>   hosts the East Coast Kinetic Sculpture Race Championship on the shore
>   of Baltimore’s Inner Harbor in central Maryland.  The eight-hour race
>   covers 15 miles—mostly on pavement, but also including a trip into the
>   Chesapeake Bay and through mud and sand.

It's quite an experience, even as a spectator.  You can dress up in costume and have a grand day, especially if the weather is nice.  I suggest if you really want to make a day of it,  bring a bike to follow the sculptures, or you can just camp out at the water entry and spend a few hours watching what most people say is the best part of the race.